# SVG linearGradiend spreadMethod ignored by Safari (OSX and iOS)

Tags: ios5, safari, svg, mobile-safari

Please look at the attached example.
It works fine everywhere (including Android) but in iOS 5.1.1 (both iPhone / iPad) Safari.
If you test it there you'll see that the linear gradient is not repeated at all as it appears everywhere else.
Is that a bug of ios safari or is there something wrong on my svg?

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   version="1.1"
   width="150"
   height="150"
   id="svg5262"
    onload="anim();">
  <defs
     id="defs5264">
    <linearGradient
       x1="0"
       y1="0"
       x2="-8"
       y2="8"
       id="linearGradient5260"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       gradientTransform="translate(0,0)"
       spreadMethod="repeat">
        <stop
             id="stop5216"
             style="stop-color:#ff0000;stop-opacity:1"
             offset="0" />
          <stop
             id="stop5218"
             style="stop-color:#7f0000;stop-opacity:1"
             offset="1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
    <script language="javascript">
        var x=0;
        function anim(){
            var gr = document.getElementById("linearGradient5260");
            gr.setAttribute("gradientTransform", "translate(" + x + ", 0)");
            x++;
            if (x>15) x=0;
            setTimeout(anim, 50);
        }
    </script>
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <path
       d="M 20,140 L 20,20 140,20"
       style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:12;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none" />
    <path
       d="M 20,140 L 20,20 140,20"
       id="path2985"
       style="fill:none;stroke:url(#linearGradient5260);stroke-width:10;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. It has been confirmed to me by Apple (bug id #10171198 at http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: @Iviggiani  Has there been a resolution for this?  I'm trying to use the SVG linearGradient with a spreadMethod of "repeat".  Works on PC but not on an iPad in either Safari or Chrome.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just reported this as a bug too (#16524230).  Hopefully I'll get a response.

Comment: @Bill Doss: unfortunately they never gave me any feedback on the reported bug :(

Answer (score 0):

@Iviggiani It seems that the spreadMethod attribute of the linearGradient tag is being ignored on the iPad (both Safari and Chrome in my tests).  Using both the SVG linearGreadient and pattern tags, I was able to create the same effect that I was getting with just the linearGradient tag, with the benefit that it works on both a windows machine and the iPad.  I got the idea from this site https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns

Here is an example of what I did (jsFiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/wahoodoss/eG5Tx/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <svg id="abc" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="Gradient1">
                x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%"
                <stop offset="40%" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1"/>
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00AA00" stop-opacity="1"/>
            </linearGradient>

            <pattern id="Pattern" x="0" y="0" width="5" height="5" 
                patternTransform="rotate(90 0 0)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <rect x="0" y="0" width="5" height="5" fill="url(#Gradient1)"/> 
            </pattern> 

        </defs>
    </svg>

    <script>
        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(40).outerRadius(100)
            .startAngle(20 * 3.141 / 180)
            .endAngle(120 * 3.141 / 180);

        var chart = d3.select("#abc")
            .attr("class", "chart")
            .attr("width", 420)
            .attr("height", 420);

        chart.append("svg:rect")
            .style("fill","url(#Pattern)")
            .style("stroke", "black")
            .attr("x", 20).attr("y",20).attr("width",120).attr("height",120);

    </script>
</body>
  </html>
```